# Google docs api - get all the document

Tags: google-drive-api, google-docs-api

Is it possible to **get all the documents** from google docs using google-docs API?

On the API reference page, **I am not able to find API for get all the list of documents**

the below api used for get single document using documentId.

```
GET https://docs.googleapis.com/v1/documents/{documentId}
```

**Reference**: https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/get

If I forget the document Id, how can get the document? this information not available on the reference api page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to retrieve all Google Document files using the method of "documents.get" in Google Docs API.
- You have no Document IDs of all Google Document files. You are required to retrieve the Document ID.

In order to achieve your goal, I would like to propose to use the following 2 processes.

1. Retrieve Document IDs of Google Document files.

   - In this case, the method of "Files: list" in Drive API is used. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list)
   - In order to retrieve Google Document files, the search query of `mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.document' and trashed=false` is used.
   - The sample curl command is as follows.

     ```
       curl \
         'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?pageSize=1000&q=mimeType%3D%27application%2Fvnd.google-apps.document%27%20and%20trashed%3Dfalse' \
         --header 'Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]' \
         --header 'Accept: application/json' \
         --compressed
     ```
   - When you want to retrieve the Google Document files in the specific folder, please use `mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.document' and trashed=false and '###' in parents` as the search query.
   - When above curl command is run, the file list including the file IDs is returned.
   - In this sample, the page size is 1000. When you have more document files, please use `pageToken`.
2. Retrieve the data from Google Document files.

   - In this case, the method of "documents.get" in Google Docs API is used.
   - Using the file IDs retrieved by above method, you can retrieve all Google Document files. In the current stage, I think that in this case, it is required to request to the endpoint for each Document ID in a loop.
   - In this case, the endpoint in your question can be used.

#### References:

- [Files: list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list)
- [Search for files and folders](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/search-files)
- [Method: documents.get](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/get)

Comment: @Shakthifuture Thank you for replying. I'm glad this is useful for your situation. Also, I think your this question will be useful for other users.